# How to kill the process using the name of the program instead of PID?

Tags: linux, unix, python, background-process, nohup

I started my Python program in the background using `nohup` as mentioned below -

```
nohup zook.py &
```

Now I am trying to kill this process so I did the `ps` command as mentioned below

```
root@phxdbx1145:/home/david/zook# ps ax | grep zook.py
16352 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto zook.py
```

But somehow, everytime its PID getting changed, I don't know why. Whenever I do like this -

```
kill -9 16352
```

It always say, `No Such Process`.

And when I do px command again, I see that PID got changed automatically..

So I am not sure how do I kill this process?

Is there any way I can kill the process with the name somehow?

I tried with

`killall zook.py`

but it doesn't work for me and I get -

```
zook.py: no process found
```

Any other option? Somehow everytime, its PID getting changed.. So I cannot use `kill -9 pid`

**UPDATE:-**

This is what I am getting. I did `pkill -9 zook.py` and then I did ps command as mentioned below and it is shwoing zook.py constantly?

```
root@dbx1145:/home/david/zook# pkill -9 zook.py

root@dbx1145:/home/david/zook# ps ax | grep zook.py
23870 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto zook.py

root@dbx1145:/home/david/zook# ps ax | grep zook.py
23872 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto zook.py

root@dbx1145:/home/david/zook# ps ax | grep zook.py
23874 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto zook.py

root@dbx1145:/home/david/zook# ps ax | grep zook.py
23876 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto zook.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at what is to the right of that PID you may notice that it is the PID of grep looking for your search string.  That is why it is different every time.  By the time you have your shell back from grep, of course grep is gone.

You will find your process under a different name, if it is still running.  Try `ps ax | grep python` instead, or better yet, `pgrep python` if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

To do the grep for the process, you could use

```
ps ax|grep name|grep -v grep
```

this will get rid of the grep commands, however if your script name is not showing up you probably have to do ps axw to get a longer command line.

```
ps axww|grep name|grep -v grep
```